# Can't get the highlight menu items on scroll jQuery script to work with WordPress Divi theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am buiding a one page WordPress website with Divi theme and I want the menu items to highlight while the page is scrolled up/down like here: http://codepen.io/ivanchi/pen/QEEeKd?editors=0010. The problem is that I can't get it to work on Wordpress. I equeued it using this code:

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets', 16 );
            
            wp_register_script( 'jqueryMinJs', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' , '', '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryMinJs' );
            
            wp_register_script( 'highlight-on-scroll', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/highlight_on_scroll.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'highlight-on-scroll' );      
}
?>
```

and I included the jQUERY script in the /js/highlight_on_scroll.js directory:

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
(function($) {

              $jq("div").css("border", "1px solid red");
  $jq("#et-top-navigation a").addClass("green-navigation");

// Cache selectors
var lastId,
 topMenu = $jq("#et-top-navigation"),
 topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+1,
 // All list items
 menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
 // Anchors corresponding to menu items
 scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
   var item = $jq($jq(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) { return item; }
 });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $jq(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $jq(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $jq('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 850);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$jq(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $jq(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($jq(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("mactive")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("mactive");
   }                   
});
}($jq));
```

I used

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

for preventing conflict and these two lines are working fine(I added them for testing purposes)

```js
            $jq("div").css("border", "1px solid red");
      $jq("#et-top-navigation a").addClass("green-navigation");
```

but the rest of jQuery script does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the jquery code not executing that your are using , as the delimiter , you should use ;

Check the plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/owvH2WPMJ10AQS3MkcHC

if you use ; then the second alert is displayed , but if you use , then code will not reach there.

```
topMenu = $jq("#et-top-navigation");
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+1;
```

Comment: Hi, Deep, thank you for your answer. I changed comma to semicolon, as you suggested, but nothing changed. It works on codepen(http://codepen.io/ivanchi/pen/QEEeKd?editors=0010) but won't work in Wordpress.